# Adding a current value as a placeholder

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml, formtastic

In my Controller I have

```
MessageContent.new(language: "en", body: "Write your english text here", title: "", sender: "Admin")
```

and in view, I want to add the body as placeholder to my input

```
 = f.input :body
```

I have been searching for the answer, but no clue.
Thx

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
# controller
@message_content = MessageContent.new(language: "en", body: "Write your english text here", title: "", sender: "Admin")

# view
= f.input :body, placeholder: @message_content.body
```

Comment: actually no. it displays as a normal text, not as a placeholder

Comment: @ishwr It does work, but you of course have to style your placeholder with some css.

Comment: as seen here e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css